# Group Homomorphism question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can there be an injective additive group homomorphism between the objects $\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb F_2^{\infty}$ where I am thinking of $F_2^\infty$ (maybe an algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_2$) as an infinite version of $char$$2$ finite field that does not respect the standard addition of vectors over the char $2$ field (meaning it respects a different additive structure in $\Bbb F_2^{\infty}$ that comes from one of the many automorphisms in the $char2$ object)?

Comment: What role does $k$ play in this? What is «an infinite version of a characteristic 2 finite field»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is a field of characteristic two, then for all $x\in F$ we have $x+x=0$.

It follows immediately that there is no additive injective homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to F$.